# Can you return an unevaluated function in scala?

Tags: scala

Given this code:

```
def getFunc(funcName:String, param:Int) = match funcName {
  case "FooFunc" => FooFunc(param)
  [...]
}

def FooFunc(param:Int) = param + SomeObject.SomeVariable
```

How could I return `FooFunc` with `param` applied, *without* evaluating it? The reason I'd want to do this is because `FooFunc`, as you can see, relies on an external variable so I'd like to be able to call it with `param` already applied. What would the return type of `getFunc` need to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lazyness must be defined at the call site, in Scala. You can do:

```
lazy val x = getFunc(...) // getFunc only gets evaluated when needed
```

Or you can change the signature:

```
def FooFunc(param:Int) = () => param + SomeObject.SomeVariable
...
val x = getFunc(...) // x contains a function from Unit into something

x() // Use x here, causing the evaluation
```

Answer (score 5):

Easy:

```
def getFunc(funcName: String, param: Int) = funcName match {
  case "FooFunc" => () => FooFunc(param)
  [...]
}
```

Your method has a good name: `getFunc` is supposed to return a function, so it will.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another void parameter, so the function is only evaluated when it is applied to this parameter.

Though I'd rather use a proper object instead of a function in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's many options, but you can use:

```
return { Unit => FooFun(param) }
```